# PHP code with MySQL search breaks in IE but works in Chrome

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, internet-explorer, foreach

Could someone help a noob like me find out why this works in Chrome but breaks in IE? This code is probably not very well put together but I'm just starting to learn and am proud I got it to work at all. :)

The first code block sends text from a textarea to the output page.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="output.php" method="post" id="artsearch">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form><br>
<textarea name="textareaname" form="artsearch" cols="53" rows="50"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

This page outputs the data in a table.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-</title>
</head>    
<body>    
<?php
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------
$servername = "-";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$dbname = "-";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------

$arr = explode("\n", $_POST['textareaname']);

echo "<table>
<tr><td><b><u>ID<td><b><u>Item<td><b><u>Place</b>";

foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE id=$value";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."<td>".$row["item"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<td>".$row["place"]; 
        }
        }
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what it is that breaks in IE, the output seems to halt just before the "foreach" command, could this be the culprit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is broken. Chrome auto-corrects for broken tags, which is why it breaks in IE. You should have a `</td>` for every `<td>`. Also, maybe headers should be put in `<th></th>` tags?

It should read:

```
echo "<table>

<tr><th><b><u>ID</u></b></th><th><b><u>Item</u></b></th><th><b><u>Place</b></u></th></tr>";

foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE id=$value";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row["place"]."</td></tr>"; 
        }
        }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it! I was so focused on the SQL code that I overlooked the HTML. 

TIL that Chrome autocorrects bad HTML which makes Chrome bad for testing, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Really weird, it no longer works. Here is my code, have I accidentally changed something else? I just get the headers now in IE but everything works fine in Chrome.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------
$servername = "-";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$dbname = "-";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------

$arr = explode("\n", $_POST['textareaname']);

echo "<table>

<tr><th><b><u>ID</u></b></th><th><b><u>Item</u></b></th><th><b><u>Place</b></u></th></tr>";

foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE id=$value";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row["place"]."</td>"; 
        }
        }
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I believe it works--look at my first answer (I edited it)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `</tr>` at the end of the row. :)

Answer (score 0):

I wish it was that easy, still doesn't work. The complete code (except database stuff);

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------
$servername = "-";
$username = "-";
$password = "-";
$dbname = "-";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------

$arr = explode("\n", $_POST['textareaname']);

echo "<table>

<tr><th><b><u>ID</u></b></th><th><b><u>Item</u></b></th><th><b><u>Place</b></u></th></tr>";

foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE id=$value";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["item"]."&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>".$row["place"]."</td></tr>"; 
        }
        }
echo "</table>";
$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the output source in get in IE;

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>-</title>
</head>

<body>

<table>

<tr><th><b><u>ID</u></b></th><th><b><u>Item</u></b></th><th><b><u>Place</b></u></th></tr>
```

Not even this works in IE so I guess the table isn't the problem. Drives me crazy.

```
// Database ---------------------------------------------------------

$arr = explode("\n", $_POST['textareaname']);

foreach ($arr as $value) 
        {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE id=$value";
    $res = $conn->query($sql);    

    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
        {               
        echo $row["id"]; 
        }
        }

$conn->close();
?>
</body>
</html>
```